# ggplot2: pass factor variable to facet_wrap

Tags: ggplot2, facet-wrap

i am trying to replace line-by-line scripting to produce ggplot2 graphics with functions - but have come unstuck with facet_wrap

To generalise the problem, I have created this toy dataset - which plots a value over time for two subjects ("IDs)

```
day <- c(0,  3,  5,  7,  9, 14,  0,  3,  5,  7,  9, 14)
value <- c(0.0, 3.6, 6.7, 7.6, 8.7, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.2, 8.3, 1.2, 0.0)
ID <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
df <- data.frame(ID, day, value)
```

With the following scripting approach, i can produce line plots of the value for the day - facetted on the two subjects

```
ggplot(df, aes(day, value)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ID)
```

I then try to do this by creating and then calling a function using this code:

```
fun <- function(data, x, y, fac){
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() 
  p + facet_wrap(~fac)
}
fun(df, day, value, ID)
```

But I get the following error:

```
 Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `fac`.
* Plot is missing `fac`
* Layer 1 is missing `fac`
```

Interesting, if I hardcode "ID" into the function, everything works - and I don't even have to pass a faceting variables

```
fun <- function(data, x, y){
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() 
  p + facet_wrap(~ID)
}
fun(df, day, value)
```

But this sort of defeats the generalising benefit of creating a function

I would be grateful if someone could tell me what i am doing wrong and what might be the work-around

Thanks

PS. I have done a check for an answer on StackExchange, and although there are several somewhat similar questions about facet_wrap, either I could not get the suggested solutions to work, or else did not understand them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because non-standard evaluation changes the scoping rules in subtle ways, you cannot simply feed variables into `aes()` or `vars()` calls within functions (the `~ formula` notation wraps `vars()`). A more detailed treatment of this problem you can find here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html

One of the solutions is to wrap you variable names into `{{...}}`, which signals that the non standard evaluation should occur with whatever expression is given as the argument, instead of the evaluated value of the argument expression.

```r
library(ggplot2)

day <- c(0,  3,  5,  7,  9, 14,  0,  3,  5,  7,  9, 14)
value <- c(0.0, 3.6, 6.7, 7.6, 8.7, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.2, 8.3, 1.2, 0.0)
ID <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2))
df <- data.frame(ID, day, value)

fun <- function(data, x, y, fac){
  p <- ggplot(df, aes({{x}}, {{y}})) + geom_line() 
  p + facet_wrap(vars({{fac}}))
}

fun(df, day, value, ID)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Also, note that you should also double bracket the `x` and `y` variables. The only reason that it worked before was because the `day` and `value` were variables in the global environment (and of the length `nrow(df)`). The following returns an error if run in a clean environment:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), 
  day = c(0,  3,  5,  7,  9, 14,  0,  3,  5,  7,  9, 14), 
  value = c(0.0, 3.6, 6.7, 7.6, 8.7, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.2, 8.3, 1.2, 0.0)
)

fun <- function(data, x, y, fac){
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() 
  p + facet_wrap(vars({{fac}}))
}

fun(df, day, value, ID)
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'day' not found
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for your solution - which works well! Not in a million years would i have been able to work this out!